# Several JSONObject keys and values won't save to Parse

Tags: java, android, json, parse-platform

I have an adapter class with a checkbox and when the checkbox is selected it pushes a JSONObject key and value to Parse. Inside my app it only saves one key and value to Parse as a JSONObject and I want my app to save several key and values into Parse when selecting other Checkboxes.

When I select a different Checkbox it changes the single key and value rather then adding another set to the JSONObject

[Photo of the row inside Parse including the JSONObject](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pGj1Q.png)

Instead I'd like to have the JSONObject inside Parse to save data like this when other checkboxes with different keys and values are selected.

```
{"2c1":true, "2c2":true, "2c3":true, "2c4":true, "2c5":true, "2c6":true}
```

instead of just having this alone

```
{"2c1":true}
```

Here is the code inside my Adapter class

**ChecklistAdapter.java**

```
   final JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject();
    try {
        myObject.put(dataRecord.getID(), true);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        String idSelected = dataRecord.getID();

        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

                ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("checklistData", myObject);
                ParseUser.getCurrentUser().saveInBackground();

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), idSelected,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CheckBox is unchecked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });
```

The functional code provided just saves on key and value pair.

**Edit: If you're curious about what the Toast does when you click the Checkbox here.**

[image]

Comment: Inside the setOnclickListener, you have added the myObject, and myObject does not seem to be modified, expect the first time which adds only one value.

Comment: @TheNeoNoirDeveloper How can I add the existing JSONObject from Parse to `myObject`?

Comment: if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

               myObject.put(dataRecord.getID(), true);
 ParseUser.getCurrentUser().put("checklistData", myObject);}

Comment: @TheNeoNoirDeveloper didn't work :( Did exactly as you did

Comment: So you're putting an object with several key/value pairs into the parse object, saving, and then only seeing one of those key/value pairs?  Have you inspected what's being set in `.put("checklistData", myObject);`?  I'd wager there's only one key/value pair in there, probably the last item checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject();

checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    String idSelected = dataRecord.getID();

    public void onClick(View v) {


        if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

        try {
              myObject.put(dataRecord.getID(), true);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
        }


            ParseUser parseUser= ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
            parseUser.put("checklistData", myObject);
            parseUser.saveInBackground();

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), idSelected,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else {

            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CheckBox is unchecked",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

In your OnClickListener, you are not updating the object you are sending to the parse database. So the object you are sending to your parse database is not getting updated. The data is set for your JSON Object only once outside your OnClickListener.

Comment: Inside Parse the data changes to the latest Checkbox clicked but it still remains to a single pair of a key and a value, rather than adding more.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem Solved**

Edit(s) made:

```
        checkBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        String idSelected = dataRecord.getID();

        public void onClick(View v) {


            if (((CheckBox) v).isChecked()) {

                JSONObject myObject;
                myObject = ParseUser.getCurrentUser().getJSONObject("checklistData");

                try {
                    myObject.put(dataRecord.getID(), true);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


                ParseUser parseUser= ParseUser.getCurrentUser();
                parseUser.put("checklistData", myObject);
                parseUser.saveInBackground();

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), idSelected,
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {

                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "CheckBox is unchecked",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
    });

    return convertView;

    }
```